# How to set the error message in a custom exception wrapper from the @NotBlank(message="...") annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation

I'm trying to create a `@ControllerAdvice` class which currently handle a `MethodArgumentNotValidException` exception. I've created an exception wrapper for the response which have an `errorMessage` and `statusCode` attribute.

```
public class ExceptionBodyResponse {
   private String exceptionMessage;
   private int statusCode;
}
```

And the `@ControllerAdvice` :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class DTOExceptionHandler {

   @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
   @ResponseBody
   public ExceptionBodyResponse handleInvalidArgumentException(MethodArgumentNotValidException exception) {
       return GenericBuilder.of(ExceptionBodyResponse::new)
               .with(ExceptionBodyResponse::setExceptionMessage, exception.getMessage())
               .with(ExceptionBodyResponse::setStatusCode, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value())
               .build();
      }
}
```

And finally, the DTO class with @NotBlank validation:

```
public class RegisterRequestDto {
  @NotBlank
  private String email;

  @NotBlank(message = "Password must not be null!")
  private String password;
}
```

What I'm expecting as response when I'm sending a JSON with this structure :

```
{
  "email":"stack@yahoo.com";
}
```

is the following error message:

```
{
  "exceptionMessage":"Password must not be null",
  "statusCode":400
}
```

Instead, I'm getting this:

```
"exceptionMessage": "Validation failed for argument [0] in public packagehere.UserDto packagehere.UserControllerImpl.save(packagehere.RegisterRequestDto): [Field error in object 'registerRequestDto' on field 'password': rejected value [null]; codes [NotBlank.registerRequestDto.password,NotBlank.password,NotBlank.java.lang.String,NotBlank]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [registerRequestDto.password,password]; arguments []; default message [password]]; default message [Password must not be null!]] ",
"statusCode": 400
```

Comment: Can you post your MethodArgumentNotValidException class?

Comment: It's not my class, is a default exception thrown by `@Valid` annotation

Comment: Well that's your issue then, you don't have control over the exception message that is thrown. I suggest creating a custom exception for this.

Comment: did u try to put a breakpoint in your excepionhandler and see if the control is coming there

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class DTOExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
            final MethodArgumentNotValidException exception,
            final HttpHeaders headers,
            final HttpStatus status,
            final WebRequest request) {
         return GenericBuilder.of(ExceptionBodyResponse::new)
           .with(ExceptionBodyResponse::setExceptionMessage, exception.getMessage())//You can customize message
           .with(ExceptionBodyResponse::setStatusCode, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value())
           .build();
    }
}
```

You can make use of `ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors()` to get the list of `FieldError`

Answer (score 0):

You need to override method inside **@ControllerAdvice** :

```
@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    List<String> details = new ArrayList<>();
    for (FieldError fieldError : ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors()) {
        details.add("{\"" + fieldError.getField() + "\" : \"" + fieldError.getDefaultMessage() + "\"}");
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(details.toString(), BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Response is JSON and looks like :

```
[
{
    "employeeLogin": "Pole wymagane"
},
{
    "type": "Pole wymagane"
},
{
    "description": "Pole wymagane"
},
{
    "name": "Pole wymagane"
}]
```

where validated object is :

```
@NotBlank(message = "Pole wymagane")
private String employeeLogin;

@NotBlank(message = "Pole wymagane")
private String type;

@NotBlank(message = "Pole wymagane")
private String name;

@NotBlank(message = "Pole wymagane")
private String description;
```

Described step by step and solved here :

https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/spring-rest-request-validation/